# $\left\{\begin{array}{lll} f_{t}+xf_{y}=0\\ f|_{t=0}=f_{0}(x,y) \end{array}\right.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given $f\in C^{1}({\bf R}^{3})$ , then find the solution of the following pde :

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
f_{t}+xf_{y}=0\\
f|_{t=0}=f_{0}(x,y)
\end{array}\right.$$

I tried to use the characteristic method to solve this question , but I failed . Any comment or advice I will be grateful .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll} f_{t}+xf_{y}=0\\ f|_{t=0}=f_{0}(x,y) \end{array}\right.$$
The characteristic ODEs are : $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dx}{0}=\frac{df}{0}$

A first family of characteristic curves comes from : $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dy}{x} \quad\implies\quad y-xt=c_1$

A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad\frac{dx}{0}=$finite$\quad\implies\quad x=c_2$

A third family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad\frac{df}{0}=$finite$\quad\implies\quad f=c_3$

Thus, the general solution of the PDE, expressed on the form of implicite equation is :
$$\Phi\left(x\:,\: (t-xt) \:,\: f \right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of three variables.
( Doesn't matter the order of the variables since the function $\Phi$ is arbitrary ).

Or alternatively, on explicit form :
$$f(x,y,t)=F\left(x\:,\:(y-xt) \right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

CONDITION :

$f(x,y,0)=f_0(x,y)=F\left(x\:,\:(y-0) \right) \quad\implies\quad F\left(x\:,\:y \right)=f_0(x,y)$

Now, the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the second variable is $(y-xt)$. This leads to :
$$f(x,y,t)=f_0\left(x\:,\:(y-xt) \right)$$

Comment: Now , I understood . This explaining is clear and sound .

Comment: You can solve the first equation in this way only after determining that $x$ is constant, as with $x$ a function the integration $y=\int x\,dt$ is not trivial.

Comment: On the characteristic we are looking for $x=c_2$. If one prefers, the above first characteristic can be introduced after the second. Doesn't matter the order.

Answer (score 2):

If the PDE was just $f_{t} + f_{y} = 0$, then you would make a travelling wave ansatz $f(x,y,t) = f(y-t)$. As the derivative in $y$ has a non-constant coefficient $x$, it stands to reason that when differentiating our solution with respect to $t$, we should get an $x$ out the front. Hence, we can guess that $$f(x,y,t) = f_{0}(x, y - xt)$$ solves the problem, which you can check by differentiation it does.

Alternatively, make the guess $f(x,y,t) = g(\alpha y + \gamma t)$ which, after differentiation, yields

\begin{align}
f_{t} &= \gamma g' \\
f_{y} &= \alpha g' \\
\therefore f_{t} + x f_{y} &= 0 \\
\implies \gamma g' + x \alpha g' &= 0 \\
\implies \gamma &= -x, \quad \alpha = 1 \\
\implies f(x,y,t) &= g(y - xt)
\end{align}

Applying the initial condition yields

\begin{align}
f(x,y,0) &= g(y) \\
&= f_{0}(x,y) \\
\implies f(x,y,t) &= f_{0}(x, y - xt)
\end{align}

Comment: yes , the function $f_0(y-xt)$ actually works .but I have no ideal that why you guess another function $g(\alpha y+\gamma t)$ to deduce the solution $f(x,y,t) = g(y-xt)$

Comment: When I said alternatively, I meant that instead of using my first line of reasoning ('it stands to reason ...'), you can make an arbitrary wave ansatz and derive the values of $\alpha, \gamma$ that satisfy the PDE.

Answer (score 2):

The method of characteristics should tell you that the characteristic curves
$$
t(s),\, x(s),\,y(s),\,z(s)=f(t(s),x(s),y(s))
$$
follow the ODE (up to re-parametrization)
$$
\frac{dt}{ds}=1,\, \frac{dx}{dt}=0,\, \frac{dy}{dt}=x,\, \frac{dz}{ds}=0
$$ 
which has solutions 
$$t=s+t_0,\, x=x_0,\, y=y_0+x_0s,\, z=z_0$$ so that for all $s$ (discounting shocks etc., i.e., in a neighborhood of $s=0$)
\begin{align}
f(t,x,y)&=z(s)=f(t_0+s,x_0,y_0+x_0s)\\
&=z(0)=f(0,x_0,y_0)=f(0,x,y-xt)\\
&=f_0(x,y-xt).
\end{align}
where obviously the initial values where chosen to conform to the given boundary condition, that is, $t_0=0$ so that $t=s$, $x_0=x$, $y_0=y-x_0s=y-xt$.

Comment: Can I ask  $t(x)~,x(s),~y(s),~z(s)=f(t(s),x(s),y(s))~$ ,what does it mean  ?

Comment: This is the parametrization of a characteristic curve of the problem. One needs to distinguish at least the function $z(s)$ from the function $f(t,x,y)$, to be perfectly correct one would also have to use different symbols for the free variables $t,x,y$ and the functions $t(s),x(s),y(s)$, but this kind of "abuse of notation" is usual in this situation.