# Geometric meaning of this PDE :$\left\{\begin{array}{lll} f_{t}+xf_{y}=0\\ f|_{t=0}=f_{0}(x,y) \end{array}\right.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I have answers for this following first order PDE [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633829/left-beginarraylll-f-txf-y-0-f-t-0-f-0x-y-endarray-righ)
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
f_{t}+xf_{y}=0\\
f|_{t=0}=f_{0}(x,y)
\end{array}\right.$$

But I just wonder what is the geometric meaning for this PDE .

Any comment or suggestion will be appreciated .Thanks for considering my request .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a two dimensional balance law or here better conservation law. With $\boldsymbol{x}=(\boldsymbol{x}_{1},\boldsymbol{x}_{2}):=(x,y)$
define $\vec{v}(t,\boldsymbol{x})=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\\boldsymbol{x}_{1}\end{pmatrix} $, the initial value problem can be written as
\begin{align*}
f_{t}(t,\boldsymbol{x})+ \operatorname{div}\left(f(t,\boldsymbol{x})\vec{v}(t,\boldsymbol{x})\right)&=0\\
f(t,\boldsymbol{x})&=f_{0}(\boldsymbol{x})
\end{align*}
Thus, the initial datum $f_{0}$ is conserved and moves in $\vec{v}$ direction dependent on $\boldsymbol{x}_{1}$ spatial coordinate.

Comment: I agree that this form should be the conservation law. But why $\operatorname{div}\left(f(t,\boldsymbol{x})\vec{v}(t,\boldsymbol{x})\right)=xf_{y}$ ?

Comment: This is just do determine what the "velocity" function of this conservation law is. And here, it seems like velocity is $\vec{v}$ which gives you an idea in which direction in the two dimensional space the initial datum is moving....So, It ransfered your problem into this standard form...